# Ubuntu 10.04 Super + M Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04

There is some crazy speculation on the <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> shortcut in Ubuntu.

It does 2 things:
1. Either invert the whole screen
2. Open that small Envelope Menu containing mail & chat notifications

now, what i want is for the 2nd to happen and NOT the first >.<

So i went to the ccsm, and disabled Negative. But now Super + M is completely unbound and neither of the shortcuts are working

Please help!

Comment: good question; I'm investigating as I want to know the general answer too, back soon..

Comment: have you tried to reassign the key after deleting the combination?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can reassign your keyboard bindings through the gconf editor. If memory serves me correctly type `gconfig` or `gconf-editor` in your terminal prompt and reassign away.

Cheers! ~Chris